# Modify structure of deeply nested object into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have a deeply nested javascript object, which can contain a properties field- which is an object where the key represent the property name and the values represent the rest of the property data. I want to transform the property object into an array of objects where the key is combined with the values.
For example, this is what i have:

```
const test = {
    properties: {
      meta: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          agencyId: {
            type: 'string',
            example: 'e767c439-08bf-48fa-a03c-ac4a09eeee8f',
            description: 'agencyId',
          },
        },
      },
      data: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          intervalStartTime: {
            type: 'string',
            description: 'Time in GMT',
            example: '1591702200000',
          },
          group: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              groupType: {
                type: 'string',
                description: 'Group Type',
                example: 'vip',
              },
              numberofRequests: {
                type: 'number',
                example: 10198,
                description: 'Amount of requests coming from group',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

And this is what i want:

```
const test = {
  properties: [
    {
      name: 'meta',
      type: 'object',
      properties: [
        [
          {
            type: 'string',
            example: 'e767c439-08bf-48fa-a03c-ac4a09eeee8f',
            description: 'agencyId',
            name: 'agencyId',
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'data',
      type: 'object',
      properties: [
        [
          {
            type: 'string',
            description: 'Time in GMT',
            example: '1591702200000',
            name: 'intervalStartTime',
          },
          {
            name: 'group',
            type: 'object',
            properties: [
              {
                name: 'groupType',
                type: 'string',
                description: 'Group Type',
                example: 'vip',
              },
              {
                name: 'numberOfRequests',
                type: 'number',
                example: 10198,
                description: 'Amount of requests coming from group',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

I have a helper function that converts the objects into the form that I want, but I am struggling with recursively modifying the nested properties. This is what I have. Any suggestions on how I can modify the entire object into the structure that I need?

```
 const convertObj = (obj) => {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((initialVal, [name, nestedProperty]) => {
      initialVal.push({ ...nestedProperty, name })
      return initialVal
    }, [])
  }

 const getNestedProperties = (data) => {
    for (const key in data) {
      const keyDetails = data[key]
      if (keyDetails.hasOwnProperty('properties')) {
        const keyProperties = keyDetails['properties']
        keyDetails['properties'] = []
        keyDetails['properties'].push(convertObj(keyProperties))
        getNestedProperties(keyProperties)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object has a `properties` key, map the entries and create an array of objects with each key as `name` and rest of the value. Loop through the object and check if each property is an object. If yes, recursively call the function. The `{ ...o }` part creates a copy of the input, so that it isn't mutated.

```js
const test = {properties:{meta:{type:"object",properties:{agencyId:{type:"string",example:"e767c439-08bf-48fa-a03c-ac4a09eeee8f",description:"agencyId",},},},data:{type:"object",properties:{intervalStartTime:{type:"string",description:"Time in GMT",example:"1591702200000",},group:{type:"object",properties:{groupType:{type:"string",description:"Group Type",example:"vip",},numberofRequests:{type:"number",example:10198,description:"Amount of requests coming from group",}}}}}}};

function convert({ ...o }) {
  for (const key in o) {
    if (typeof o[key] === 'object')
      o[key] = convert(o[key])
  }

  if (o.hasOwnProperty("properties"))
    o.properties = Object.entries(o.properties).map(([name, v]) => ({ name, ...v }))

  return o
}

console.log(convert(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no `properties` property, just return the rest of the object.  If you do, return the rest of the object plus a `properties` array property formed by taking each name-value entry in that property and converting it into an object by adding the property `name` to the result of calling `transform` on that `value`.

The code is fairly simple:

```js
const transform = ({properties, ...rest} = {}) =>
  properties 
    ? {
        ... rest, 
        properties: Object .entries (properties) .map (([name, val]) => ({
          name, 
          ... transform (val)
        }))
      }
    : {... rest}

const test = {properties: {meta: {type: 'object', properties: {agencyId: {type: 'string', example: 'e767c439-08bf-48fa-a03c-ac4a09eeee8f', description: 'agencyId'}}}, data: {type: 'object', properties: {intervalStartTime: {type: 'string', description: 'Time in GMT', example: '1591702200000'}, oup: {type: 'object', properties: {grupType: {type: 'string', description: 'Group Type', example: 'vip'}, numberofRequests: { type: 'number', example: 10198, description: 'Amount of requests coming from group'}}}}}}}

console .log (transform (test))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) does the heavy lifting. Note that this works because traversal happens in delete safe order.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const test = { properties: { meta: { type: 'object', properties: { agencyId: { type: 'string', example: 'e767c439-08bf-48fa-a03c-ac4a09eeee8f', description: 'agencyId' } } }, data: { type: 'object', properties: { intervalStartTime: { type: 'string', description: 'Time in GMT', example: '1591702200000' }, group: { type: 'object', properties: { groupType: { type: 'string', description: 'Group Type', example: 'vip' }, numberofRequests: { type: 'number', example: 10198, description: 'Amount of requests coming from group' } } } } } } };

const rewrite = (obj) => objectScan(['**.properties'], {
  rtn: 'count', // returns number of rewrites
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    parent[property] = Object.entries(value)
      .map(([name, v]) => ({ name, ...v }));
  }
})(obj);

console.log(rewrite(test));
// => 4
console.log(test);
// => { properties: [ { name: 'meta', type: 'object', properties: [ { name: 'agencyId', type: 'string', example: 'e767c439-08bf-48fa-a03c-ac4a09eeee8f', description: 'agencyId' } ] }, { name: 'data', type: 'object', properties: [ { name: 'intervalStartTime', type: 'string', description: 'Time in GMT', example: '1591702200000' }, { name: 'group', type: 'object', properties: [ { name: 'groupType', type: 'string', description: 'Group Type', example: 'vip' }, { name: 'numberofRequests', type: 'number', example: 10198, description: 'Amount of requests coming from group' } ] } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)